# Java memory leak detection with finalize

Tags: java, debugging, memory-leaks, finalizer

Ok I've read lots of articles over the net speaking about the `finalize()` method and the fact that a we cannot really rely on it...

Right, it's clear (I guess)

But when memory leaks occur, and before going deeper and deeper inside VisualVM, can I just use the `finalize` method as a primary debugging tool ?

(A tiny Log message like "object released" in finalize and a "object created" in the constructor)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Do you mean like overriding the finalize method to produce a log message? I don't see how thats going to help you debug anything. finalize(), if not called explicitly (which it shouldn't) will be called by the gc at a 'unpredictable' time. Essentially called when the gc feels like it... I fail to see how knowing when its called helps with debugging.

Comment: Short answer: "no".  Even if the method _will_ be called (it's not guaranteed...) you don't know **when** it's going to be called, even if the object is sitting, waiting to be collected (ie, no further references) - especially with more modern computers allowing a larger VM share, some programs may never actually reclaim memory from un-referenced objects.

Comment: No.  Java and finalizer have been around since 1995.  If this were fruitful, it'd be common practice by now.

Comment: If your memory leak is so severe it causes your application to fill the available memory, you might get some results with finalizers, because the GC should really try to collect whatever can be collected, before calling a OutOfMemoryError. But it can only work if you already have a clear idea of which objects are not being released. Though, if you have such a precise idea, maybe a usage search with the help of your IDE will work better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to trace object being retained, not those being released (which is what finalize shows you).  More importantly, you want to know why objects are being retained, i.e. the path of references which are holding onto them.  I suggest using VisualVM as a start, and possibly a commercial profiler if the heap is large or the problem is obscure.

I have use finalize() for logging when a resource has not been cleaned up deterministically. i.e. it should have been close()d by was not.

Comment: I haven't seen a commercial profiler that compares to Visual VM.

Comment: @duffymo Agreed, but possibly not in the way you mean ;) VisualVM is next to useless in low latency applications as it creates more garbage and places much more load on the application than what it is trying to monitor.  I use YourKit which runs without creating garbage in you VM and its load CPU wise is not so bad.

Comment: Thank you for your usual insight, Peter.  I've used JProbe, BlackBox, and Dyna Trace.  I like the lovely visuals and ease of use from VisualVM, but I'll agree that it may not be the ultimate tool for all situations.  Only Sun JVMs, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Generate heapdump/ System core by adding jvm arguments.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html
Then Download  http://eclipse.org/mat/  tool.
Load the generated dump in the above tool
Then follow as shown in the image [image]

By Selecting finalizer overview, It will give information on the number of objects ready to get cleared by finalizer thread and associated information of finalizer thread.